# Advice on Optimization routine/Constraints to use

Tags: algorithm, optimization, math, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to do some numerics and having a difficult time determining the appropriate way to solve a problem and looking for some feedback.

So far I have done all my work in Mathematica, however, I believe that the time has come where I need more control over my algorithms.

I can't post Images yet so here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx3Rj.jpg) to them 
Where H is the heaviside stepfunciton.  `C(k)` is just the FT of `C(r)` and `m=4`.  `N` in my case is `2000` so you can see the omega is mearly the sum of a large number of exponentials.  `rho` is just the densitiy.  `C(r)` as you can see because `m=4` has for different `a` coefficients.  IRISM is ultimately a function of those for `a` coefficients.

I have these three equations working correctly I think within Mathematica however I am trying to minimize IRISM and find the 4 `a` values.  The problem I am having is that, for obvious reasons, there is a discontinuity when the log with in the integral is equal to zero.  I cannot seem to find a way to modify the Mathematica Algorithm (they are blackbox is that the right term?) so as to check the trial `a` values.  I was using Nelder-Meade and Differential Evolution and attempting different constraints.  However, I seemed to only get either imaginary results, obviously from a negative Log, or if I constrained well enough to avoid obviously only local minimum as my results did not match the "correct" results.  I tried a few times with minimization algorithms that used gradients however I did not have much luck.

I think my best way to move forward is to just write a minimization routine from scratch, or modify other code, so as I can check IRISM ahead of integration for discontinuity.  I have read up some on penalty function, log-barrier etc. but being somewhat new to programming was hoping someone might be able to let me know what a good approach would be to start off with.  I think more than anything there is almost too much information out there on optimization and I am finding it difficult to know where to begin.

Edit: Here is the raw input.  If I need to post it in a different way please let me know.

```
OverHat[c][a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, k_] := (a1*(4*Pi*(Sin[k] - k*Cos[k])))/k^3 + 
   (a2*(4*Pi*(k*Sin[k] + 2*Cos[k] - 2)))/k^4 + 
   (a3*(8*Pi*(2*k - 3*Sin[k] + k*Cos[k])))/k^5 + 
   (a4*(-(24*Pi*(k^2 + k*Sin[k] + 4*Cos[k] - 4))))/k^6

Subscript[OverHat[\[Omega]], \[Alpha]\[Gamma]][k_, \[Alpha]\[Gamma]_, n_] := 
  Exp[(-k^2)*\[Alpha]\[Gamma]*((n - \[Alpha]\[Gamma])/(6*n))]

OverHat[\[Omega]][k_] := Sum[Subscript[OverHat[\[Omega]], \[Alpha]\[Gamma]][k, \[Alpha]\[Gamma], n], 
    {\[Alpha]\[Gamma], 1, n}] /. n -> 2000

IRISM[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, \[Rho]_, kmax_] := 
  \[Rho]^2*(1/15)*(20*a1 - 5*a2 + 2*a3 - a4)*Pi - 
   (1/(8*Pi^3))*NIntegrate[(\[Rho]*OverHat[\[Omega]][k]*OverHat[c][a1, a2, a3, a4, k] + 
       Log[1 - \[Rho]*OverHat[\[Omega]][k]*OverHat[c][a1, a2, a3, a4, k]])*4*Pi*k^2, 
     {k, 0, kmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 80]

NMinimize[IRISM[a1, a2, a3, a4, 0.9, 30], {a1, a2, a3, a4}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Comment: You could post your Mma code. I added the Mma tag so the Mma community here could help you.

Comment: I have added the Mathematica code.  I am using a working precision of 80 so as to avoid numerical noise resulting from the k^6 in the bottom for small values of k.  I am looking for a way to get the "correct" answer in such a way to post.  It is a graph from an old paper that I converted with DataThief. I am sure that this code can be improved greatly.  I think I can probably reduce the accuracy and precision goals and possibly try interpolating the omegahat function as it is a summation of 2000 exponentials.  But these are just a few ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica's `FindMinimum` aborts if it sees an imaginary number. This can happen even if your objective is real-valued inside the constraints because for default Barrier method because it poor accuracy control and can occasionally step out of bounds. Simplest way around it is to wrap your objective inside `Re`. You may get better answers if you post complete code.

Some general advice:

It's easier to try to simplify your objective for Mathematica than re-implement optimization algorithms. The reason is that one algorithm failing often means it's a difficult problem, and other algorithms will fail as well.

I once had a problem where `FindMinimum` gave warnings and failed to converge to correct minimum, which I could determine analytically, it happened with different methods, and it made sense when I plotted the objective surface, below

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/so-plateau.png))</sub>

In this case, you can see the problem is very badly conditioned at the minimum (it's almost a plateau) and minimum is hard to localize.

When you have inequality constraints, default method is Barrier method, which is expensive and offers poor precision control. Very inefficient thing to do is to specify equality constraints as pairs of inequalities, ie instead of `a=b`, have `a>=b` and `a<=b`. This can be 3-10 times slower, and also numerically worse -- a and b might be only approximately equal in the result.

Ideally the goal is to get a problem which is convex, doesn't have any inequality constraints and is well conditioned.

Comment: That is actually a good idea.  I tried doing something similar but only tried Re around what was inside the Log portion.  I will try it around the whole expression.  Thank you for your advice.